# How to use an IF ELSE command

Tags: batch-file

I am a beginning coder creating a text-based game on batch and I am wondering how to say the following in code:

```
If {these variables} have been defined 
Then goto {this loop} 
Else goto {other loop}
```

If anyone has a link to a tutorial or can answer in a stack answer that would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Do all of the variable's have to be defined? Do you need to know which are/aren't?

Comment: Did you at least open up a command prompt and read the help for the `IF` command? Type: `IF /?`

Comment: @Compo Yes i do need all variables to be defined previously, this may not be possible, but idk for sure

Comment: @Squashman Thanks, I looked, but what I need is to define variables in a separate loop than say if said variables are defined than continue otherwise return to a central loop

Comment: That doesn't abstain you from at least trying to code it.  If you read the help file you would know that there is no `THEN` in the syntax and the ELSE syntax is pretty clear on how it works.  Parentheses are required.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one way you could test to see if all variables you need are defined. You can use a `FOR` command to loop through all the variable names and use an `IF` command to see if they are defined.  I then set two counters.  One for the total number of variables and one for the total number of variables that are defined.

```
@echo off

REM Change these variables to test logic
set "var1=one"
set "var2=two"
set "var3=3"

set "allvars=var1 var2 var3"

set "vcnt=0"
set "defcnt=0"
FOR %%G IN (%allvars%) do (
    set /a vcnt+=1
    IF DEFINED %%G SET /a defcnt+=1
)

IF %vcnt% equ %defcnt% (
    GOTO allvars
) else (
    GOTO notdefined
)

:allvars
echo All variables defined
GOTO END

:notdefined
echo Some variables not defined
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Put that into a loop breaking if just one var isn't defined

```
For %%A in (these variables) Do If not defined %%A goto :otherloop
Echo all vars defined
Goto :eof

:otherloop 
Echo not all vars defined
```

Comment: Yep.  That short and simple.